# Fetch all images from the public folder after building the app [React + Vite]

Tags: reactjs, image, import, vite, react-typescript

I am going to create a gallery. I do not want to store files on an external server, so the main idea is to store all images in the public folder. The main assumption is to be able to add more files to the list after building the app. I am using the React + Vite framework.

I attempted to fetch all files from my `public/gallery` folder. `import.meta.glob` returns functions that return promises. Therefore, I called each function and obtained the URLs of the files.

```
interface ImportImageData {
  default: string
}

type ImportImageGlob = () => Promise<ImportImageData>
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchGallery = (): void => {
      const images: ImportImageGlob[] = Object.values(
        import.meta.glob('/public/gallery/*')
      ) as ImportImageGlob[]

      _.forEach(images, (fetchImg: ImportImageGlob): void => {
        fetchImg()
          .then((data: ImportImageData): void => {
            setDataSource((prev: string[]): string[] => {
              return _.uniq([...prev, data.default])
            })
          })
          .catch((): void => {})
      })
    }

    fetchGallery()
  }, [setDataSource])
```

In the development app version, everything works perfectly. However, in the production version, the file list does not refresh. When I add a new image, only the previous files are shown.

Is `import.meta.glob` dynamic or does it get built as static text when the Vite framework builds the app? How can I resolve this issue? Is there an alternative approach I can take?

Thank you in advance